# Depth Texture in Panda3D

Tags: python, 3d, panda3d

In Panda3D, I have the following code

```
self.manager = FilterManager(base.win, base.cam)

self.sceneTex = Texture("scene")
self.depthTex = Texture("depth")


self.quad = self.manager.renderSceneInto(colortex=self.sceneTex, depthtex = self.depthTex)

...
```

When I run the above and enable view buffers (show-buffers #t), the "sceneTex" texture looks right. However, "depthTex" is always blank (all black) no matter where I move the camera to. Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have disabled your depth test writing ? Even though you might not get any obvious artifacts (depends on your scene) you could be running without a depth buffer. Look in the [panda tutorial about depth buffer writing](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Depth_Test_and_Depth_Write) it also tells you about some scenes work better with depth sorting (you perhaps tested this but not reverted your depth buffer disabling code?)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  I had to create a custom shader to extract the depth.  Since I wanted more than 8 bits of depth information, I had to convert the depth into 3 8-bit fields that could go in the RGB components of the image.

In Panda3D Python:

```
# Set up Shader
dcam = loader.loadShader('Dcam.sha')
# render everything through this camera and shader
self.terrain.getRoot().setShader(dcam)
```

The shader inputs and outputs also need to be set up (i.e. vtx_position, mat_modelproj, etc.  See the examples in the Panda3D documentation.

In Dcam.sha:

```
//Cg

void vshader(float4 vtx_position : POSITION,
             uniform float4x4 mat_modelproj,
             out float4 l_position : POSITION,
             out float4 l_pos : TEXCOORD0)
{
    float4 position = vtx_position;
    l_pos = mul(mat_modelproj, position);
    l_position = l_pos;
}

void fshader(in float4 l_pos : TEXCOORD0,
             out float4 o_color : COLOR)
{
    float z = (l_pos.z / l_pos.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    float zres = 16777216.0 * z;
    float v0 = round(zres / 65536.0);
    zres = zres - 65536.0 * v0;
    float v1 = round(zres / 256.0);
    zres = zres - 256.0 * v1;
    float v2 = round(zres);
    o_color = float4(v0, v1, v2, 1);
}
```